# Test if File/Dir exists over SSH/Sudo in Python/Bash

Tags: python, bash, ssh, fabric

I am installing certificates on a remote server and want to check whether they exist before I overwrite them. The server only allows non-root access via ssh public key. I can `sudo -s` to root once in a shell. Root is required because /etc/ssl is not readable by anyone else. This is being developed in `python fabric`, so any command that can be run in a shell command via `sudo` would work. I don't mind typing in passwords at prompts in this case.

**TL;DR:** I need an `sh` command that can tell my python program whether a remote file (or directory) exists when run as `if fabric.sudo(sh_command) == True:` (or something similar).

Thank you!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
from fabric.contrib.files import exists

def foo():
    if exists('/path/to/remote/file', use_sudo=True):
        #command
```

Comment: Link to doc: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/files.html?highlight=exists#fabric.contrib.files.exists

Comment: This function was moved to the patchwork library as of fabric v2.0 https://github.com/fabric/patchwork/blob/master/patchwork/files.py

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the simplest way, but out of my head, I would suggest

```
ssh user@server 'bash -c "if [ -e /path/to/remote/file ] ; then true ; fi"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a command like [test](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_test.htm) in Linux to figure out whether a directory exists or not. The output of **fabric.sudo** is a multline-string, that can be parsed for the return status.