# python fabric check if hadoop file exists

Tags: python, hadoop, fabric

I have three servers. I run a python script a.py in server1 and a.py will connect to server2 which has hadoop client. Then, from server2, I need to check if server3 has hadoop directory dir_eg or not.

How to do this in a.py?

`fab -H server2 exe_cmd_in_server2:hadoop fs -mkdir server3/dur_eg` is the command to create that dir, but I need check if it exists

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if File/Dir exists over SSH/Sudo in Python/Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916144/test-if-file-dir-exists-over-ssh-sudo-in-python-bash)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid an error if the directory already exists you could use `mkdir -p 'path'`.
If you want to know if the directory exists you can use [`fabric.contrib.files.exists`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/files.html).